# Multiple calls to async function with cache in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a function that can be called from many UI elements at the same time:

**In Psudeo code**

```
public async Task<Customer> GetCustomer(){
   if(IsInCache)
      return FromCache;

   cache = await GetFromWebService();
   return cache;

}
```

If 10 UI element all call at the same time, how do I make sure **GetFromWebService**() is called just once, it is very expensive.

Comment: Don't check the cache there , make another layer somewhere inbetween the GetFromWebService() that stops and checks a cache,  If the GetFromWebService is filling the cache - I do not see why it would be hit more then once

Comment: @ScottSelby This method that he's writing here, `GetCustomer`, *is* the method that goes between `GetFromWebService` and the actual callers that checks the cache first.

Comment: Side note: if you are using DI container (like Unity) in your code you may be able to make such caching code more generic by handling it on container level instead of on per-method level. See [interception with Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx) for information/sample.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `Lazy`.

```
//the lazy can be changed to an instance variable, if that's appropriate in context.
private static Lazy<Task<Customer>> lazy = 
    new Lazy<Task<Customer>>(() => GetFromWebService());
public Task<Customer> GetCustomer(){
   return lazy.Value;
}
```

This will ensure that exactly *one* `Task` is ever created, and that the web service call isn't made until at least one request is made.  Any future requests will then return the same `Task` (whether its in progress or complete) which can be awaited to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

If your cache is in-memory, you can cache the task rather than the result:

```
private Task<Customer> _cache;
public Task<Customer> GetCustomerAsync()
{
  if (_cache != null)
    return _cache;
  _cache = GetFromWebServiceAsync();
  return _cache;
}
```

Comment: Would it work if 2 callers will "await" at the same time? I assume yes since you know everything about async :), but it may be good idea to explain a bit why it is safe.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yes, it is safe. Any number of `async` methods may safely `await` the same task. In this case, `_cache` is not multithread-safe, but since the OP specified "multiple *UI* components", I assume it doesn't have to be.